# Can anybody identify this flower for me?

Tags: species-identification, flowers

[image]

One single flower on small 2 year old tree with alternate leaf arrangement

[image][image]

Comment: What is your location?  Do you know if this is an ornamental specimen, or something native?  The flower strongly suggests the family Malvaceae (think hibiscus).